# Error while assigning item level permission using SP 2010 Workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, item-level-permissions

I am using SP 2010 environment and have created on designer workflow for setting the item level permission.Each item has a string field in the list with values as "SPGroupName1;SPgroupName2;SPgroupName3" 
I want to provide unique permissions to above mentioned groups.
While assigning this complete string workflow throws error while running.

Please guide me on this.

Thanks,Kailash

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say where goes wrong without information about how you configure the workflow. Basically, i assume you want to assign different permissions to groups according to how user chose in the item column. You will need first to use if condition to compare the choice column value to know which group the user choose. Then set list item permissions on corresponding groups.

Here is an example you can start with:
http://johnliu.net/blog/2010/7/13/sharepoint-2010-configuring-list-item-permissions-with-workf.html

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look into. Btw I resolved it by placing the string values inside people field

Comment: @KailashSahoo Glad to hear that. You can reply with your solution and mark it as answer. It will help other community members